# TXT to publish the data in the table

Tags: php, javascript

**// Please do not give bad votes //
// I need your help on this issue //**

TXT Data: http://www.dhmi.gov.tr/UcusBilgileri/2/domarr.txt

How do I own it on my website on a regular basis?

Details: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb05A.png

Note: I'm sorry for my bad English

Comment: You shouldn't be sorry for your English, but you _should_ be sorry for how bad this question is

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you mean you don't know how to extract the data from the State website / you wish to build a parser for the csv to output in the display / you wish to write a php script to enable the user view data stored on your server?

Comment: @spiritusozeans, Thank you for answer, I want to publish my website TXT data.. Is this possible?

Comment: So based on your image, I understand you already possess the mechanism to extract and get a hold of file.txt as well as a php script to enable the guests to view it. Isn't that it? Everything else must be trivial. If by publishing you mean simply uploading the txt file, you could use any ftp tool for example

Comment: I have everything but I need some code.. I do not know how to do it.. What do you think of my code that I need? @spiritusozeans

Comment: The way I see it, all you need is a way to upload your files to a server. If you use Linux, you could use Gnome's nautilus-connect-server (this is the easiest way if you are a beginner). You might also want to look into sftp and sshfs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read the text file and split the values to columns in a table try this:

```
<?php
$handle = @fopen("domarr.txt", "r");

while (!feof($handle))
{
    $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);

    if (strlen(trim($buffer)) > 0){

            list($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,$g,$h,$i,$j)=explode(",",$buffer);

            $items[] = array('col1' => $a,'col2' => $b,'col3' => $c,'col4' => $d,'col5' => $e,'col6' => $f,'col7' => $g,'col8' => $h,'col9' => $i,'col10' => $j);

    }
}
?>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
      <th>Col 4</th>
      <th>Col 5</th>
      <th>Col 6</th>
      <th>Col 7</th>
      <th>Col 8</th>
      <th>Col 9</th>
      <th>Col 10</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach($items as $value) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?= $value['col1'] ?></td>
      <td><?= $value['col2'] ?></td>
      <td><?= $value['col3'] ?></td>
      <td><?= $value['col4'] ?></td>
      <td><?= $value['col5'] ?></td>
      <td><?= $value['col6'] ?></td>
      <td><?= $value['col7'] ?></td>
      <td><?= $value['col8'] ?></td>
      <td><?= $value['col9'] ?></td>
      <td><?= $value['col10'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: !!! You are amazing! Yes! working now! Thank you so much Sbml! @Sbml

Comment: Col 5-> 1105  -- Between 11 and 05 ":"  How can I put the sign? for example: 11:05

Comment: @TheSaracoglu for example for Column 6 <td><?= preg_replace("/^(.{2})/", "$1:", $value['col6']); ?></td>

Comment: Thak you so much so times.. Thank you! This is my last request: http://s14.postimg.org/9rrxhvzb5/Untitled_2_fw.png   - Is this possible? - Please

Comment: @TheSaracoglu You should do some research before asking but yes its easy: where you have   <td><?= $value['col2'] ?></td>    change to:    <td><?php if($value['col2'] == "THY"){ echo '<img src="path_to_turkish_airlines_logo.png"'; }elseif($value['col2'] == "YB"){ echo '<img src="path_to_borajet_logo.png"'; }else{ echo $value['col2']; }  ?></td>    DON'T FORGET TO CHANGE THE IMAGE PATHS

Comment: YES!! You are a expert! Really! You are a person skilled! Thank you times infinity! SBML!!

Comment: @TheSaracoglu  sorry, works but some code is wrong, change to  <td><?php if(trim($value['col2']) == "THY"){ echo '<img src="path_to_turkish_airlines_logo.png" />'; }elseif(trim($value['col2']) == "YB"){ echo '<img src="path_to_borajet_logo.png" />'; }else{ echo $value['col2']; } ?></td>

Comment: Thank you for your kind attention! I'm telling all my heart, you are very good man!